# Sum an array in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sum, reduce

I have an array of objects with some car data inside :

```
const cars = [
{
"id": 1,
"car_make": "Lincoln",
"car_model": "Navigator",
"car_year": 2009,
"data": {
  "rating": 4.9,
  "engines": [3, 4, 5, 6]
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"car_make": "Mazda",
"car_model": "Miata MX-5",
"car_year": 2001,
"data": {
  "rating": 4.1,
  "engines": [1, 2]
}
},]
```

Next I need to sum all the engines numbers inside the data object in car: So I made the next function but everytime I try to console the array it remains unchanged.

```
cars.forEach(car => {
car.data.engines.reduce((a,b) => a+b,0)
})

console.log(cars);
```

Comment: What do you thing `forEach` does?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking forEach changes an intial array without making a new one? I made a mistake by not declaring a new variable to hold that new Array but I still get undefined when declaring a new array that holds the new data.

Comment: `forEach` just iterates, it doesn't make any changes

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the reduce value to `engines` again

so change

```
car.data.engines.reduce((a,b) => a+b,0)
```

to

```
car.data.engines = car.data.engines.reduce((a,b) => a+b,0)
```

```js
const cars = [
{
"id": 1,
"car_make": "Lincoln",
"car_model": "Navigator",
"car_year": 2009,
"data": {
  "rating": 4.9,
  "engines": [3, 4, 5, 6]
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"car_make": "Mazda",
"car_model": "Miata MX-5",
"car_year": 2001,
"data": {
  "rating": 4.1,
  "engines": [1, 2]
}
}]

cars.forEach(car => {
  car.data.engines = car.data.engines.reduce((a,b) => a+b,0)
})

console.log(cars);
```

Comment: Ohhh thanks a lot, I didnt get the idea that I need to assign a new value to that engines array and not just changed that directly, thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer to the question should have been an map and create a new array from that old with the data changed.

```
const newCars = data.map(car => ({
id: car.id,
brand : car.car_make,
engineSum : car.data.engines.reduce((a,b) => a+b,0),
})).sort((a,b) => a.engineSum - b.engineSum);

console.log(newCars);
```